# allow the user to change his order values in the data base

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-views

i want to allow the user to change a value in his order from the data base

The idea is when the user press the delete button the value of visible changes from yes to no and he won't be able to see it on the profile

i managed to pull out all the user's orders

but i couldn't find a way to make the button change the value for the order of that current user only

is there any way to do such thing??

**models.py**

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    status_ch = [('in process', 'in process'), ('complete', 'complete')]
    visible_ch = [('yes', 'yes'), ('no', 'no')]
    status = models.CharField(
        choices=status_ch, max_length=20, null=True, blank=False, default='in process')
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    saller = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)
    product = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)
    currency = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    phone = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=False)
    amount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    accountId = models.TextField(default='', blank=False)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    image = models.ImageField('Label')
    visible_for_saller = models.CharField(
        choices=visible_ch, max_length=20, null=True, blank=False, default='yes')
    visible_for_buyer = models.CharField(
        choices=visible_ch, max_length=20, null=True, blank=False, default='yes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.saller
```

**views.py**

```py
@login_required
def profile(request):
    orders = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'app/profile.html', {'orders': orders})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are using the `visible` attributes as booleans, so I recommend doing:

```
visible_for_saller = models.BooleanField(default=True)
visible_for_buyer = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Then, if I understood it well, you don't want to delete the order, just make it invisible for the user right?
If that's the case, the button you want to make have to call a view in which you just change the `visible_for_buyer` attribute, right? this could be the view:

```
def delete_order_for_buyer(request, pk):
    user = request.user  # you get the loged user
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=pk)  # you get the order through the pk
    if order.user == user:  # you check if the user is the owner of the order
        order.visible_for_buyer = False  # set the attr to false
        order.save()  # save that specific object
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))  # you redirect to the page you came (you can change this for whatever you want)
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied()  # in case someone that is not the user tries to execute that view through the url you make, it will raise an error.
```

Then you just need to add the url you want for it like:

```
    path('order/<pk>/delete/', views.delete_order_for_buyer, name='delete-order'),
```

And finally on the view where you list all the orders (in case you have many, you can make an if statement in which you check if the `visible_for_buyer` is true or false:

```
{% if order.visible_for_buyer %}
  show content here
{% endif %}
```

With all that little information you gave I had to asume lots of things but I suppose this will help you

Comment: thank you it worked greate i just had to change some things like order.user == user not order.user != user and the path i used the <int:order_pk> so i can use the correct order i hope that will not couse any problems with the permission

Comment: true, I'll edit the if statement. about the bath, as I put it here it should work well because the pk is always an int. of course you have to use the pk of the order you need, but if you want you can use the path as I explained here because it will work correctly.

Comment: okay thank you so much for the explanation and everything i really appreciate your help